# What matlab command, or combination of commands (using 25 characters or less), could be used to create the following matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

What matlab command, or combination of commands (using 25 characters or less), could be used to create the following matrix?

```
1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0
1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0
1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0
1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

Hint: Look for a lower triangluar matrix that is repeated many times. First try to produce that lower triangular matrix with as few characters as possible.

Comment: Such questions are more related to [CG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following code:

```matlab
A = ones(5); % create 5x5 matrix with all elements 1
B = tril(A);  % return the lower triangle matrix of A
C = repmat(B, 3, 2); % repeat the matrix B, 3 times in a row and 2 times in a cloumn as you want.
```

In more details:

```
A = ones(5); 

1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1

B = tril(A);


1 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1

C = repmat(B, 3, 2);

1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution using `rempat` and implicit expansion:

```
repmat(1:5<(2:6)',3,2)
```